# How to encapsulate CSS properties to prevent repeating myself

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm adding two CSS properties to an element which both have the same value:

```
var hex = window.lineColors[a.options.labels.length - 1];

$('.container#buttonContainer').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:' + hex + '; border-color: ' + hex + '">' + date.format("DD/MM/YYYY") + '</button>');
```

As you can see both `background-color` and `border-color` share the same value `hex` and I'm trying to explore the best way to remove this duplication.

As `hex` contains one of a number of pre-selected values one possibility is to have a CSS class for each, for example:

```
button_003C69
{
   background-color: #003C69;
   border-color: #003C69;
}
```

and I could generate these automatically with a pre-processor.

I was also hoping I could somehow pass the hex to a CSS class for it to use, but only a pre-processor would allow this and therefore not available in runtime.

*I just know* I'm missing a trick here, how do you guys best deal with this scenario?

Comment: CSS variables? (No IE suport yet, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

One option is just to declare a standard **transparent** border.

Then the background color shows *through* the border.

```css
button {
  /* demo properties */
  width:200px;
  height:75px;
  display: block;
  margin:10px auto;
  border-width:5px;
  border-style:solid;
  /* transparent border */
  border-color:transparent
}

.A {
  background: pink;
}

.B {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<button>No Class</button>
<button class="A">Button A</button>
<button class="B">Button B</button>
```

Comment: Out of the box thinking, I like it!